# File upload control in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a fileupload control in asp.net mvc.But as of now the logic what i am doing is, i am downloading excel file in to server locally and then processing data and pushing in to oracle database.But some servers due to permission issues , i am not able to retrieve data from downloaded server or download in to server in either way. I would like to have a logic which will convert the uploading files in to a stream or what ever rather downloading in to server locally .I dont know whether i can implement `HttpPostedFileBase.inputstream` if so how can i implement it here?

VIEW

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "mnis", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @*<div>
        <label for="file">Filename:</label></div>
        <div class="uploadfirst">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></div>

        @Html.Label("lbl", "PSITE_SLNO");
        <input id="Text1"  name="txtsln" type="text" />
        <div class="upload">
        <input value="Submit"  type="submit" /></div>*@

        <table>
            <tr><td><label for="file">Filename:</label></td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td class="positions"><input value="Submit"    type="submit" /></td></tr>
        </table>

    }

CONTROLLER
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    int slno = (int)(Session["slnum"]);
                    string st = file.FileName.ToString();
                    //st = Server.MapPath("~/")+st;
                    st = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), st);
                    file.SaveAs(st);
                    //Start(st, slno);

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Maximo thread";

                        Start(st, slno);
                    });
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    RedirectToAction("Index");
                    //  file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
```

Comment: i posted answer try that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

You can Get Stream From `InputStream` of Fileuplpad Control then you can convert Stream to byte Array for saving into database

```
    Stream stream = file.PostedFile.InputStream;
    byte[] byteArray = ReadFully(stream);



 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```